# Junit test cases for Swing application

Tags: java, swing, junit

I,m new to JUnit and Swing its possible to write JUnit test cases for Swing applications especially for ActionListeners which represents like below...

```
public class sampleFile extends JFrame{
    JTextField userText = new JTextField(15);
    JLabel lable;
        JTextField name;
        JPanel panel;
    JButton submit;
        JFrame frame;
     sampFile(){
        lable.setBounds(60, 200, 200, 30);
        text.setBounds(130, 200, 165, 25);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(text);
        frame.add(panel);
        submit.addActionListener(e -> sendActionPerfrm())
     }
     private void sendActionPerfrm(){
      -------------
        All validations for the text from textfield goes here  
      -----------  
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look for [AssertJ Swing](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I work for Jalian Systems that maintains Marathon

You can use [marathon java driver](https://marathontesting.com/javadriver/) which provides webdriver bindings for testing Swing and FX applications. This [blog article](https://marathontesting.com/software-testing/unit-testing-swing-apps/) provides step by step instructions.